# Auto increment and user defined id using hibernate anotation

Tags: hibernate, auto-increment

Can I use hibernate annotation to set auto-increment AND user-set id for the same field?

E.G: 
If the user inputs the ID, use the given ID

-OR-

If the user didn't input anything, Hibernate should create the ID itself.

I'll be grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
```

Comment: Baadshah, Thanks for replay. Actually I am looking something else. Because, by using this configuration, If I try to save record with ID which is input from user(not generated by Hibernate), in that case hibernate not allowed me to save it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are bound to Hibernate you could user custom id generator.Suppose you have following id field for which you want to have id if provided by user otherwise it sholud be auto generated.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator="CustomIdGenerator")
@GenericGenerator(name="CustomIdGenerator ",
                  strategy="xx.yy.zz.CustomIdGenerator"
)
private Integer id;
```

Here's the custom generator which will generate id if not provided.

```
import org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator;
...
public class CustomIdGenerator extends IdentityGenerator {


@Override
public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object obj) throws HibernateException {

    if ((((yourEntity) obj).getId()) == null) {
        Serializable id = super.generate(session, obj) ;
        return id;
    } else {
        return ((yourEntity) obj).getId();

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Piyush, Is it posible that I use GenerationType.IDENTITY and if id is null then GenerationType.IDENTITY get call or something like that as I don't want to create Generator?

Comment: That is what the Generator is doing man!!! Anyway Somewhere you need to check if the id is null..Custom generator is Overriding default generation behavior of AutoSequenceGenerator.

Comment: @Piyush, I try this solution but it gives me null value when I didn't set id(In this case it should return me new id). when I debug, `Serializable id = super.generate(session, obj)` location I recieve `POST_INSERT_INDICATOR` object of `IdentifierGeneratorHelper$2`